# Dialogbox in webview

Tags: android

I want to display alert message while changing from one page to another. By clicking on button,it should load the target page. Here is my code. I am using android studio 2.3.3. Its not working. Can u suggest any modifications? Thank u...

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

 if(url.equals(Common_variables.BASE_URL + "s.changePswd.php")) {

    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Send_OTP.this);
    b.setMessage("OTP has sent to your mail id");
    b.setCancelable(true);
    b.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
     {
      @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
Intent regIntent = new Intent(Send_OTP.this,Forgot_password.class);
                    startActivity(regIntent);
     }
   });

  AlertDialog alert = b.create();
  alert.show();
  }
   else
      sendOTPwv.loadUrl(url);

 return true;

  }

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest 
       request)
  {
 if(request.getUrl().toString().equals(Common_variables.BASE_URL + 
                "s.changePswd.php"))
  {
     AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(Send_OTP.this);
     b.setMessage("OTP has sent to your mail id");
     b.setCancelable(true);
     b.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
     {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       dialog.cancel();
 Intent regIntent = new Intent(Send_OTP.this,Forgot_password.class);
    startActivity(regIntent);
  }
 });

    AlertDialog alert = b.create();
    alert.show();

   }

   else
     sendOTPwv.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
     return true;
     }
     }
  }
```

please suggest what i have to make changes in the code.

Comment: Which OS of Android are you using for testing?

Comment: "Its not working": What exactly is not working? The `AlertDialog` is not showing up, or it does show up but clicking on OK doesn't start the desired activity?

Comment: Can you log your request.getUrl() and Common_variables.BASE_URL +"s.changePswd.php" and paste it in your question.

Comment: @Chandankushwaha-Android 4.2, API 17

Comment: @pleft-alertdialog is not showing, it directly loads another page.

Comment: sorry @mudit_sen, I didnt get your question.

Comment: I think url.equals(Common_variables.BASE_URL + "s.changePswd.php") is equals to false. try with if(true) once